# Flask WTForms {{ form.input(value=something.something) }}

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to render an html form and pass in a table row with sqlalchemy. So then the form will show up with all it's input fields filled with the row data, with the purpose of editing and sending it back to the db. But somehow the form is displaying only two input fields, both of type text. Integer fields and radio fields are not showing the row's each corresponding value, although the values exist and are not none.

Here's the route:

```
@app.route('/editar/<string:id>')
def hotel_edit(id):
    form = HotelForm()
    viaje = arribos.query.get(id)
    return render_template('edit_hotel.html', form=form, viaje=viaje)
```

Here's the html file displaying the wtform object + trying to get the object "viaje" to show the values with no luck:

```
{% block body %}
<div id="main_form">
    <form action="/" method="post" id="ingresos">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="checks" id="inout">
                {{ form.check.label }}
                {{ form.check(value=viaje.check) }}
            </div>
            <div class="horafecha">
                {{ form.fecha.label }}
                {{ form.fecha(value=viaje.fecha) }}
                {{ form.hora.label }}
                {{ form.hora(value=viaje.hora) }}
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                {{ form.vuelo.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.vuelo(class="inputtext", value=viaje.vuelo) }}
                {{ form.habitacion.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.habitacion(class="inputtext", value=viaje.habitacion) }}
                {{ form.huespedes.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.huespedes(class="inputtext", value=viaje.huespedes) }}
                {{ form.valijas.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.valijas(class="inputtext", value=viaje.valijas) }}
            </div>
            <div class="checks" id="puerto">
                {{ form.puerto.label(class="puertos") }}
                {{ form.puerto(class="puertos", value=viaje.puerto) }}
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                {{ form.enviar }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And here's the form (not styled yet):
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USa0c.png)

As you can see, most of the input fields are missing the value. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also: I can show you the form.py file that has the class definition for the entire form, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the form before it's sent to the jinja template from within your route. It would look something like this:

```
@app.route('/editar/<string:id>')
def hotel_edit(id):
    form = HotelForm()
    viaje = arribos.query.get(id)
    form.check.data = viaje.check
    form.fecha.data = viaje.fecha
    form.hora.data = viaje.hora
    ...

    return render_template('edit_hotel.html', form=form)
```

You can then just refer to the form field without passing the value arg.

```
{% block body %}
<div id="main_form">
    <form action="/" method="post" id="ingresos">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset>
            <div class="checks" id="inout">
                {{ form.check.label }}
                {{ form.check() }}
            </div>
            <div class="horafecha">
                {{ form.fecha.label }}
                {{ form.fecha() }}
                {{ form.hora.label }}
                {{ form.hora() }}
            </div>
            <div class="textbox">
                {{ form.vuelo.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.vuelo(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.habitacion.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.habitacion(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.huespedes.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.huespedes(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.valijas.label(class="inputtext") }}
                {{ form.valijas(class="inputtext") }}
            </div>
            <div class="checks" id="puerto">
                {{ form.puerto.label(class="puertos") }}
                {{ form.puerto(class="puertos") }}
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                {{ form.enviar }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I would add to this that you should be able to do `viaje = arribos.query.get(id)` followed by `form = HotelForm(obj=viaje)`. Reference: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.__init__